# How to validate that an API received all data sent to it

Tags: python-3.x, api, rest, flask

I'm creating a Python client/server application that sends data to my Flask REST API and I want to ensure that the server received all of the data that was sent.  Initially I was going to try and calculate an MD5 hash of the data before sending it and then have the server calculate the hash of the data received, but long story short, that turned out to be a huge pain due to the fact that dictionary ordering is not guaranteed so calculating the hash proved to be challenging to the point of me revisiting this process.

So, my question: is it really necessary to write code to verify that the server received the data intended if it provides the client with a success response, or is that a false trust?  I mean, I could do some simple check on the server and have it respond with the number of records received, or the length of the JSON text or something like that.  I just want to make sure that I'm doing my due diligence to make sure that I either build ample fault-tolerance or utilize existing mechanisms that are already in place to make sure my data makes it to the server in its entirety.  Any other suggestions as for how to approach this would be much appreciated.

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: Are you the owner of the server? If so, you make the call as to what the server should expect and then design the applications that communicate with it to adhere to those restrictions. If you do not own the server, then consult the related documentation and design your system to adhere to the specified server expectations.

Comment: As I wrote in my question "I'm creating a Python client/server application" - I own both the client and the server because I'm creating them.  And as I asked in my question, I'm looking for suggestions as to how to design it so that it's as fault-tolerant as possible.  Yes, I can make the call to do whatever I want, but what I think is right might not be the best/most efficient, hence my reason for asking the experts here.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I glossed over the "/server" in client/server. What type of API are you building? REST? GraphQL? JSON-Pure? These different design decisions may have some baked-in fault tolerance support to help you make the informed decision you are looking for. I am no expert on the matter, so my comments were only seeking to clarify your question from "suggestions", which are opinion based, to a more targeted one that would garner a response rooted in fact.

Comment: It's a Flask REST API - sorry, I only put Flask API - I'll add REST to the question as well!